# Sending CER/CEA manually when starting JDiameter stack

Tags: restcomm

I am using jdiameter and want to send CER/CEA manually (by default jdiameter takes care of that and I found no API to trigger a CER/CEA). Is it possible ?

I tried to ask this in https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter/issues/88
- but it seems was not the right place to ask such question as per the collaborator and I was suggested to put the question here. So far I was able to create diameter server and client stack and make communication between then successfully.